# Is the interpretation of the data visualization bellow, which uses Python libraries, correct?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram, data-science

I am trying to practice data science skills with some real data. I got the data on Breast Cancer from the [link](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/). The  specific file with the data that I am using is `breast-cancer-wisconsin.data`.

After downloading the file, I tried to have a big-picture of the data so I did:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing, cross_validation, neighbors
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('breast-cancer-wisconsin.data.txt')
print(df.head())
```

Which returns the following table as output:

```
id  clump_thickness  unif_cel_size  unif_cel_shape  marg_adhesion  \
0  1000025                5              1               1              1   
1  1002945                5              4               4              5   
2  1015425                3              1               1              1   
3  1016277                6              8               8              1   
4  1017023                4              1               1              3   

   single_epith_cell_size bare_nuclei  bland_chrom  norm_nucleoli  mitoses  \
0                       2           1            3              1        1   
1                       7          10            3              2        1   
2                       2           2            3              1        1   
3                       3           4            3              7        1   
4                       2           1            3              1        1   

   class  
0      2  
1      2  
2      2  
3      2  
4      2
```

Reading the 'data-set' documentation I realized that  the last column, concerning classes, has two options: 2 and 4.  The number 2 is used for benign tumour and the number 4 is used for malignant tumour.

I decided to investigate the column unif_cel_size, which indicates on a scale from 1 up to 10 the 'Uniformity of Cell Size'. Hence, I ploted the following histogram:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing, cross_validation, neighbors
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('breast-cancer-wisconsin.data.txt')
print(df.head())  
df['unif_cel_size'].hist()
plt.show()
```

The image that the code returns is:

[image]

I decided that it would be interesting to see how the histogram changes if you group the cells as malignants and benigns. So, I did:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing, cross_validation, neighbors
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('breast-cancer-wisconsin.data.txt')
print(df.head())  
df.groupby('class')['unif_cel_size'].hist()
plt.show()
```

And the output is:

[image]

Now we reach my doubt. My interpretation on this result was: the relation between cells sizes and tumour types is assymetric. One of the classes concentrates on small sizes and the other concentrates on bigger cell sizes.

(i) Is this interpretation correct? Am I making some mistake?

(ii) How can I use matplotlib to indicate  which color represents which class?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(i) Your interpretation is correct. However, if you want to be even more thorough, you could do some statistical test to assess how much this difference is significant (it would be probably very significant)

(ii) If you want the legend, this works:

`df.groupby('class')['unif_cel_size'].plot(kind='hist',legend=True)`

If you're interested in going further in data science, you could try to see how good of a predictor is the unformity of the cell size (and maybe other factors). In this case, you would split your dataset into train and test, and build a model (for instance with sklearn, and do some logistic model).